# Capture network traffic with python

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, packet-capture

I want to start the capturing, send a message via signal and stop the capture in python. I want to measure the time of the packets.
The problem is, i cant sniff and send at the same time.

I tried sniff() with scapy but i could not manage to start sniffing, send the message and stop sniffing.
any idees?

Comment: Is there any reason in particular why you're not just using Wireshark or pcap?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.